# What is an oauth domain

Tags: oauth

What is an `oauth` domain? Are there any free `oauth` services? Can I use it for a [StackApps registration](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register)? I googled a lot for these but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by free oauth services. Do you mean programming libraries. Do you want to use StackApps to authenticate users for your own service, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @JonNylander Don't worry about it. I understood it all wrong at first.

Answer (score 2):

It is the domain in which [`redirect_uri`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) to which users are redirected after `OAuth 2.0` authentication is present.

> Desktop applications cannot participate directly in OAuth 2.0 flows,
>   however the embeddable browser controls available in most frameworks
>   make it possible to work around this limitation.
>
> Desktop applications should use the implicit client-side flow, hosting
>   the process within a browser control. For redirect_uri, a value of
>   https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success should be used. Upon a
>   successful authentication, access_token will be placed in the url hash
>   as with a standard implicit authentication.

So is it safe to use https://stackexchange.com/oauth/ as the `OAuth` domain for a desktop app? Can anyone confirm?